# Get cookie values to load on page change

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hi I have this script: http://flamencopeko.net/styleswitch.js that linked to from all pages on my site http://flamencopeko.net. It works fine, except that the stored values are not applied when changing page. The functionality and cookies themselves are fine i believe. The preferences just won't stick visually.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function increaseTableSize() {
   var t = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
   for(i=0;i<t.length;i++) {
       t[i].style.width = 1000+"px"
   }
}
function decreaseTableSize() {
   var t = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
   for(i=0;i<t.length;i++) {
      t[i].style.width = 677+"px"
   }
}
function setTableSize() {
   var t = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
   for(i=0;i<t.length;i++) {
      t[i].style.width = selectedwidth+"px"
   }
}

function increaseFontSize() {
   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
       p[i].style.fontSize = 16+"px"
   }
}
function decreaseFontSize() {
   var p = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
      p[i].style.fontSize = 10+"px"
   }
}
function setFontSize() {
   var t = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
   for(i=0;i<t.length;i++) {
      t[i].style.width = selectedsize+"px"
   }
}

var selectedwidth=readCookie("peko_table")
if (document.getElementByTagName && selectedwidth!=null) //load user chosen width from cookie if there is one stored
setTableSize()

var selectedsize=readCookie("peko_font")
if (document.getElementByTagName && selectedsize!=null) //load user chosen font from cookie if there is one stored
setFontSize()
```

This is the code for the four buttons in toc.php:

```
  <a href="javascript:createCookie('peko_table','600',50); decreaseTableSize();"><img src="/ico/standard.gif" width="12" height="12" hspace="1" vspace="1" />slim</a> / 
  <a href="javascript:createCookie('peko_table','1000',50); increaseTableSize();"><img src="/ico/wide.gif" width="12" height="12" hspace="1" vspace="1" />wide</a> / 
  <a href="javascript:createCookie('peko_font','10',50); decreaseFontSize();"><img src="/ico/minus.gif" width="12" height="12" hspace="1" vspace="1" />small text</a> / 
  <a href="javascript:createCookie('peko_font','18',50); increaseFontSize();"><img src="/ico/plus.gif" width="12" height="12" hspace="1" vspace="1" />large text</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running your JavaScript before the page has even been parsed.

Move the JavaScript include for styleswitch.js from the head to immediately before the closing body tag.

Comment: Thank you SO much. I wouldn't have thought of that in like forever. Everything is working now, Lee! I found a couple of other bugs myself.

Comment: Any way to speed up the page transitions? Default style is always shown for about a second first.

Comment: @OleSørensen ha ha, the way your JavaScript works, no.  A better approach would be to have JavaScript in the head to read the cookie and alter the `className` of your HTML element, then use CSS to set the width of your page/size of your text depending on the className of the HTML element.  So: redesign, or live with it!